# Easing not working

Tags: jquery

in the following example I am trying to add easing (`easeInCubic`) to a jQuery animation, but it is having no effect. Why?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("button").click(function(){
                $("div").animate({ left: 200 }, 'slow', 'easeInCubic');
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <button>Start Animation</button>
    <div style="background:#98bf21;height:100px;width:100px;position:absolute;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: jQuery only defines `linear` and `swing` (swing is the default). Seems you're trying to use a jQueryUI extension without including jQueryUI

Answer (score 2):

You have two options here:

1. Add the following to the beginning of your code, and your current script will work as is:

   ```
   $.extend($.easing, {
       easeInCubic: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
           return (c*Math.pow((t/d),3)) + b;
       }
   });
   ```
2. Or, you can download **[danro](https://github.com/danro)'s [jquery-easing.js](https://github.com/danro/jquery-easing/blob/master/jquery.easing.js),** which is where that script comes from, and which includes the full suite of easing functions.

Comment: Edited with the equation!

Comment: should I include along with with what I have already ? only the foolowing ?
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themename/jquery-ui.custom.css" />
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.custom.min.js"></script>

Comment: @theftprevention heh, I come from the world of C, where you'd walk the plank (I'm a day late…) for writing `(t/=d)*t*t`. Not a good habit to have, tbh. In some languages (like C), it will give different answers on different computers.

Comment: I edited my answer again, @user2622004. Danro's [**jquery-easing.js**](https://github.com/danro/jquery-easing/blob/master/jquery.easing.js) is a better option if all you need is the easing functions; no need to include all of jQuery UI.

Comment: @Dave I changed the formula to be [hopefully] less plank-worthy. In my defense I didn't write it; it was copied from jquery-easing.js. :P

Answer (score 1):

The `easeInCubic` functionality is part of the [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) library. You'll need to include in in your `html` right underneath the *jQuery* library. *jQuery* only includes `linear` and `swing`.

Answer (score 0):

You have yo include jQuery UI; the library extend the jQuery `easing` animations.

Quick ref:

> Easing functions specify the speed at which an animation progresses at
>   different points within the animation. jQuery core ships with two
>   easings: linear, which progresses at a constant pace throughout the
>   animation, and swing (jQuery core's default easing), which progresses
>   slightly slower at the beginning and end of the animation than it does
>   in the middle of the animation. jQuery UI provides several additional
>   easing functions, ranging from variations on the swing behavior to
>   customized effects such as bouncing.

See: http://api.jqueryui.com/easings/

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/kVLzr/